# custom post type archive slug vs. custom page template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, slug

I registered a custom post type for events and now I asked myself how to handle upcoming events and events in the past properly.

By now, I'm displaying upcoming events on a custom page template I assigned to a page and use the custom post type archive to display events that took place in the past.

My problem is that the custom post type archive now has the URL `mysite.com/events` which I would rather use for the upcoming events page and for the archive, I'd want to put something like `mysite.com/event-archive` or such.

It seems easier to reverse the method and modify the archive query in order to display future events on the custom post type archive and have `mysite.com/events` while creating a custom page template for past events and make it use the slug `event-archive`... But isn't that wrong?

- How would you properly handle upcoming events and past events?
- How do I modify the archive page URL?

Comment: Why would it be wrong? Are you familiar with the `pre_get_posts` action?

Comment: I don't know but it didn't quite feel right to put future events into an archive. Yes, I am familiar with the `pre_get_posts` action. I would use that to modify the archive query.